# Ошибка компиляции при выводе в maskedBox

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Доброго времени суток хорошим людям. Первый раз решил программировать в Windows Forms и всё никак... Помогите, кто может. Ошибка:

> `error C2664: void System::Windows::Forms::Control::Text::set(System::String ^): невозможно преобразовать параметр 1 из "System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox ^" в "System::String ^"`

Кусок кода, где происходит ошибка:

```
private: System::Void maskedTextBox7_MaskInputRejected(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MaskInputRejectedEventArgs^  e) {
    maskedTextBox7->Text=maskedTextBox1;
}
```

В C++ полный новичок, особенно в ООП.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно докам [MaskedTextBox.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.text(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Получает или задает текст, отображаемый в текущий момент.

Поэтому свойство одного Text должно присваиваться свойству другого Text. То есть должно быть:

```
 maskedTextBoxX->Text = maskedTextBoxY->Text;
```